# Python custom exception not giving message in proper syntax

Tags: python, exception

In the following code snippet, I get the response as -

`__main__.CheckSumNotMatched: ('Kirti matches with - ', 'Kirti', ' . They are same.')`

```
class CheckSumNotMatched(Exception):
    """Raised when the remote file's checksum doesn't match with local file checksum"""
    pass

def test(name):
    try:
        if name=="Kirti":
            error_msg = 'Kirti matches with - ', name, '. They are same. '
            raise CheckSumNotMatched(error_msg)
    except CheckSumNotMatched as csnm:
        logger.error(csnm)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test("Kirti")
```

I want the response as - 
`__main__.CheckSumNotMatched: Kirti matches with - Kirti. They are same.`

I don't want ( and ' in the response. 
What should be the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace

```
error_msg = 'Kirti matches with - ', name, '. They are same. '
```

with

```
error_msg = 'Kirti matches with - ' + name + '. They are same. '
```

Comment: `+` is a string concatenation operator in python while comma is a tuple operator. Previously error message was a tuple and not a string that's why there were brackets.